# Comment diviser les mots longs en syllabes ?

Tags: prononciation, phonétique

Je voudrais savoir comment faire pour diviser les mots longs en syllabes comme

> inconstitutionnellement

Afin de les prononcer correctement

Y a-t-il une astuce ou une règle ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les mêmes règles de prononciation s'appliquent. Personnellement, je divise mentalement le mot en "sous-mots" (non forcément en morphèmes). Par exemple, si je dois prononcer le mot *inconstitutionnellement*, je le diviserai mentalement en *in*, *constitutionnel* et *ement*. Mais cette division ne doit pas pouvoir s'entendre l'oral.